# Issue with getting user input into a Dynamic array C

Tags: c, arrays, input

I seem to be having trouble getting user input into a dynamic array in C.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void){
    int counter = 0;
    int x = 1;
    int i;
    printf("Enter the number of teams playing in the league: \n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    char teams[i];
    for (counter = 0; counter < i; counter++){
        char teams[counter];
        printf("Enter team names: \n");
        scanf("%s", teams);
    }
    for (counter = 0; counter < i; counter++){
        char teams[counter][10];
        printf(" Team %d is %s \n", x, *teams);
        x++;
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get a the following output,

```
Enter the number of teams playing in the league: 2

Enter team names: Team1

Enter team names: Team2

 Team 1 is Team1 

 Team 2 is \320\365\277\357\376 

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Not able to figure out my mistake. Would love any and all help.

Thank You!

Comment: Do you understand that `char teams[counter][10];` is an altogether separate variable definition?

Comment: ...and that `char teams[counter];` is as well, and this variable is destroyed once you exit the loop?

Comment: There are numerous issues, too many to address.  I'll answer your question though -- `teams` should be an array of `char *` rather than an array of `char`.

Comment: OHhhh, I guess I'm still too much of a noob, I understand my mistakes now though. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

There are some basic mistakes, especially with your understanding of pointers and C language concepts. "team" is an array of char pointers, and char teams[i] isn't quite correct; one correct way is to dynamically allocate memory for the collection of team names. By comparing the code below to yours, I am sure you can spot the areas where you made mistakes. PS: I am using the format character "m" inside scanf to dynamically allocate memory for the team name.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int counter = 0;
    int i, ret;
    char **teams;
    printf("Enter the number of teams playing in the league: \n");
    scanf("%d", &i); // check return value yourself
    teams=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*i);
    if(NULL==teams) perror("not enough memory"), exit(1);
    for (counter = 0; counter < i; counter++){
        printf("Enter team names: \n");
        ret=scanf("%ms", &teams[counter]);
        if(ret<1)//hanndle error. i'll just quit.
            exit(-1);
    }
    for (counter = 0; counter < i; counter++){
        printf(" Team %d is %s \n", counter+1, teams[counter]);
        free(teams[counter]);
    }
    free(teams);    
}
```